# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for Gridview Delete Button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, gridview

I am currently trying to get my button working in my Visual Studio Page.

I am running some code in my page an it keeps returning this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.  Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> Line 466:            Delete.OnClientClick =
>   String.Format("Javascript:HiddenPopup('deletePopup', {0}');", Cell2)
>
> Source File:
>   \BATMAN\Sales\Transfer\Website\QuotemanDJ3\Production\PlantAndMaintenance.aspx.vb
>   Line: 466

I have looked at lots of solutions online but i still cant seem to figure out what I am refrencing wrong, If I could get some assistance with this it would be much appreciated.

This is my VB code:

```
  Protected Sub Service_History0_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Service_History0.RowDataBound

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim pdfExtention2, wordExtention2, excelExtention2 As ImageButton

    pdfExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("PdfExtention2")
    wordExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("WordExtention2")
    excelExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("ExcelExtention2")

    If e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/pdf" Then
        pdfExtention2.Visible = True
    ElseIf e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/msword" Then
        wordExtention2.Visible = True
    ElseIf e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/vnd.ms-excel" Then
        excelExtention2.Visible = True
    End If

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim ImgBtn As New ImageButton
    ImgBtn = e.Row.FindControl("PdfExtention2")
    ImgBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History0.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")

    Dim ImgBtn2 As New ImageButton
    ImgBtn2 = e.Row.FindControl("WordExtention2")
    ImgBtn2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History0.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")

    Dim ImgBtn3 As New ImageButton
    ImgBtn3 = e.Row.FindControl("ExcelExtention2")
    ImgBtn3.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History0.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim Cell2 As String

    Cell2 = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ServiceID").ToString


    Dim Delete As Button
    Delete = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteInduction")
    Delete.OnClientClick = String.Format("Javascript:HiddenPopup('deletePopup', '{0}');", Cell2)
    connection.Close()


        '-----------------------------------------------------------------



End If
```

End Sub

This is my Markup Code for my gridview (My button is inside my gridview):

```
<asp:GridView 
                ID="GridView1" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" DataKeyNames="ServiceID,ID" >
                 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" >
                 </AlternatingRowStyle>
                 <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial No" HeaderText="Serial No" SortExpression="Serial No" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Record Type" HeaderText="Record Type" 
                        SortExpression="Record Type" Visible="False" >
                         </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceID" HeaderText="ServiceID" 
                        SortExpression="ServiceID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" 
                        Visible="False" />
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageURL="~/icons/pdf.gif">
                                 </asp:ImageButton>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" ID="DeleteInduction" />
                                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DeleteInduction_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="cancelButton" 
                                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="deletePopup" 
                                TargetControlID="DeleteInduction" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>


             </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Some guidance with this would be appreciated, Thankyou in advance.

Comment: an object is NULL (no value) . Debug the project (F5) and put a breakpoint (F9) in the file at the line. Good luck. maybe Delete = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteInduction") does not find anything and is null..

Comment: Can you show the rest of the VB code above the `Dim Delete...`? My guess is that this is not happening in the right place (it should be in the Grid Row Bound event, can't remember the exact name).

Comment: I edited it so it shows the whole code now @Tallmaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your code here:

```
Delete = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteInduction")
Delete.OnClientClick = String.Format("Javascript:HiddenPopup('deletePopup', '{0}');", Cell2)
```

`FindControl()` returns `null` if it [doesn't find the control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  When that happens, the immediate next line will throw that exception because you can't reference a property (`OnClientClick`) from `null`.

You can prevent the error simply by checking if the result is `null`:

```
Delete = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteInduction")
if (Delete != null)
    Delete.OnClientClick = String.Format("Javascript:HiddenPopup('deletePopup', '{0}');", Cell2)
```

Then the question becomes, what do you want to do when it *is* `null`?  Anything at all?  The above code will just silently ignore it.  Do you instead want to do something else?  That's where you'd do it:

```
Delete = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteInduction")
if (Delete != null)
    Delete.OnClientClick = String.Format("Javascript:HiddenPopup('deletePopup', '{0}');", Cell2)
else
{
    // handle the case where DeleteInduction wasn't found.
}
```

Keep in mind, for example, that some events in controls don't always apply to data-bound rows.  Depending on the event which contains this code, you could also be processing the code on header and/or footer rows which wouldn't contain the `DeleteInduction` control.  In those cases you'd likely want to just ignore the code entirely.

For example in a `GridView` you can check the row type before executing your logic:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // put your row logic here
}
```

Comment: I figured out my problem, I was referencing the wrong Gridview in my VB, dope!

Comment: But I will bear this answer in mind since I didnt know much about how it worked until now, Thanks